# calling opener function from popup while using iOS WKWebView popup window

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, popup, wkwebview

I've been changing `UIWebView` to `WKWebView` for iOS WebView based app recently.

There is a `window.open` function in WebView's javascript and popup window calls opener(parent)'s function like below

```js
// In parent window's javascript
window.open('popup' .....)

function doIt(){
}


// In popup window's javascript
window.opener.doIt()
```

In UIWebView, I used JSContext so that popup window can call opener's javascript function.

```c
// Legacy code for communication between 2 UIWebView windows
// Not works when using WKWebView
JSContext *parentCtx = [parentWebView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
JSContext *childCtx = [popupWebView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
childCtx[@"window"][@"opener"] = parentCtx[@"window"];
```

It seems like, however, `JSContext` is not available while using WKWebView. How can I link two webviews with in javascript context in this case?
What should I do to call opener's function without changing legacy javascript code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a mistake!

When popup webview was instantiated in `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView?`, I created a webview, added as subView and **returned nil**. That's the reason `window.opener` is null on javascript.

So the approach and solution is totally same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50992704/1358117).

If you return appropriate webview during webview creation in WKUIDelegate, there is no need to set JSContext for `window.opener` communication.